# Activator unwrap code from text

Tags: c#, reflection, activator

I was wondering myself if is that possible I download the C# class source text from a webserver and use Activator to unwrap and use this code.

Is that possible to do ?

Comment: I've answered the question but if you tell me exactly what you're trying to achieve I believe there may be simpler alternatives than what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No but yes.  You can't add inline source code in C# if it hasn't been compiled.  You can use scripting languages to do this like Python or F#.  You can however parse the code out and use reflection to create a dynamic assembly and run the code but you're technically writing a mini compiler inside of your source code to do this and it would be a MASSIVE undertaking.

Comment: oh I see, I was trying to keep my scripts safe on the webserver but use scripting language as Python and F# gonna take me to many effort I thought that was possible to keep my Script.cs on the web download it and then execute using activator while the program is running.

But thank you very much.

Comment: You should look into cloud computing or maybe just a good ole web service.  This would be code that ran on the server and spit back the information you need or look into Azure and other cloud computing technologies.  You can, in those situations, have code running on a server as if it was native to your PC (give or take..)